# Cybex Recumbent exercise bike clicks on left side of wheel/pedal

Tags: recumbent, clicking, indoor, stationary-bike

I just got a used Cybex recumbent bike.  For the first 3 weeks it worked perfect.  Then out of the blue the left pedal started clicking as I bring my foot around and up. It starts after using it for a minute or so.  I would like help to help me fix it in laymen's terms.  My husband has MS and it is up to me to do the handyman stuff now. I am able and willing to learn, just need basic descriptions and patience!

[image: Cybex recumbent exercise bike]

Comment: I added the image to make a it a little more obvious what you're dealing with. If that's not a good pic please edit the question with a better one. From a  quick online search it seems they use standard bike pedals (9/16" thread).

Comment: A few things to try: does the pedal make a noise if you rotate it while holding the crank arm still?  Does the click happen if you just turn the crank arm?  By setting a low resistance and knealing down to operate the cranks by hand you may be able to locaise the noise.  Of course it mauy only occur under load, which makes things a little harder.

Comment: My first reaction is a broken ball in the ball bearing of the pedal. The way to check for that is to get peddling up to speed, when the clicking begins you lower the presure on one pedal at a time. Replacing pedals is not that expensive and will take care of the click if it is the pedal is faulty.