# What power adapter to use for the Cybex 700 stationary bike?

Tags: parts, indoor, stationary-bike

An old [Cybex 700](https://s7d2.scene7.com/is/content/CYBEX/Marketing%20Materials/Flyers/700_Bikes_lr.pdf) stationary bike stopped being useful as the control panel doesn't turn on.

There is a power socket but I don't know what power adapter to use: [the user manual](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2781/4920/files/cybex700r700crecumbentbike.pdf) doesn't say, nothing I tried fits. What could be a compatible power plug?

Comment: P.s.: I think this question fits here and I've seen others like https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/37345/19258 . My understanding is that it's not a "shopping" or "product recommendation" question of the kind frowned upon https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276/do-we-go-shopping https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1215/where-to-send-people-for-product-recommendations?rq=1 because it's not opinion-based, it's asking for a mere electrical fact. Please forgive me if I misunderstood the house rules!

Comment: Generally there is often a voltage and polarity specification next to the power inlet, either a label or a relief print. May be hard to see, use a flashlight.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Good point, but I've checked again and there's nothing of the sort. It might be on the bottom, but I'm not going to turn the bike upside down.

Answer (score 6):

Most information appears to have vanished from the official website, but other specifications suggest it's just a 12V power plug.

I've tested a [universal power supply](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07XD9SYYN/) and 12 V, 1 A turned out to work fine with the Cybex 700. The correct plug was the green one in this model (6.3*3.0 mm).

Answer (score 2):

For a R700 Cybex bike the power supply needs to be 12V 1A (higher is ok), and the plug is referred to as a TIP-C or generically the exact specifications are 2.5mm x 5.5mm barrell plug.